# How to get list of user from array of User id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an array like

```
$user_id = [1,10,15,8,6];
```

and I want to get a list of this user using the `get_users` method.

```
$args = array(
        'role'    => 'any',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

but I don't know how to pass an array of user ids to get only those users. I don't need to get all users, I just need user list which has ids 1,10,15,8,6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hii parth I just do a pretty solution.

```
$user_id = [1,10,15,8,6];
$args = array('include' => $user_id );
$users = new WP_User_Query($args);
$users = $users->get_results();
```

no for loop no more queries enjoy.
also check the WordPress documents below that might be help you in some of more queries.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it's working perfectly from my side.

```
$user_data = array();
$user_ids = array(1,10,15,8,6);

foreach($user_ids  as $user_id){
   $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
   if(!empty($user)){
       $user_data[] = $user;
   }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($user_data); exit;
```

Note: get got all user information as array formate.

**Updated**

If you don't want to loop you can use include inside query like this:

```
$user_ids = array(1,10,15,8,6);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 
    array(
       'include' => $user_ids,
       'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
       'order'   => 'ASC'
     ) 
);

$users = $user_query->get_results();

echo "<pre>"; print_r($users); exit;
```

Comment: but its not good idea to use a for loop and again add fire a queries inside a loop its affect a loading time if user having a list of big data.